Is my passport damaged
my sister and scuffed the visa page of my passport with a, will it be considered a damaged?
i want to go to gulf country


This question has been asked many times; for an overview of questions and answers addressing potentially damaged passports, search Travel.SE (using the search box at the top of the page) for "damaged passports."

While no one here (or anywhere) can predict what a particular Immigration officer will do in this case, your sister's marks seem quite minor.
"Damage" will be seen as serious if it interferes with the data page(s) or the photograph, or shows some intent to make the passport unreadable by machine. Those issues don't seem to be raised by your passport's condition, so I think it is very likely that you will have no difficulties in using this passport.

It's impossible to predict exactly how immigration officers will react to this, but my guess is that this won't be a problem at all.
I'm saying this because my own passport looks much worse from stains left by the immigration stamps themselves and I never had problems. In addition, this looks like one of the last pages which is unlikely to be thoroughly checked.
